# r Data Table gives different result when using With

Tags: r, data.table

I'm wondering if there is a logical reason why Data Table gives different results when pointing to a column directly or by a character.

For example

```
library(data.table)

iris_dt <- data.table(iris)

iris_dt[, NROW(unique(Species))]

# 3

col <- 'Species'

iris_dt[, NROW(unique(col)), with = FALSE]

# Prints the Sepal Length, which does not make sense to me
```

What is happening in the second part of the code?

Comment: What does `unique('Species')` give you?

Comment: ok, then I understand why it returns the first column. But why doesent it return "3"? As I'm simply trying to call a column by a character vector instead of directly as in the first statement.

Comment: It returns the length of your character object `"Species"` which is `1`. What you want is probably `iris_dt[, NROW(unique(iris[col])), with=FALSE]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second part of the code you are selecting the first column of the data.table.

```
# Equivalent too
iris_dt[, 1, with = FALSE]
# Because
NROW('Species') == 1 # TRUE

# Also 
unique('Species') == 'Species' # TRUE
```

`'Species'` is just a (character) vector of length 1 and `NROW()` returns its length.

What I think you are looking for is:

```
iris_dt[, uniqueN(get(col))] # 3
```